# Remote Debugging with Continuous Delivery - failure locating dependency

Tags: visual-studio, azure, tfs

With TFS2013 and VS2013, I am attempting to modify a functional CI build definition to allow for remote debugging an Azure application, using [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-virtual-machines-dotnet-continuous-delivery-remote-debugging/). I have successfully followed all steps, but am receiving a cryptic dependency error on the Build Agent:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.4\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets (985): CloudServices61 :
Cannot find module named 'RemoteDebuggerConnector' at obj\Debug\RemoteDebuggerConnector\RemoteDebuggerConnector.csplugin.
```

As far as I can tell, all dependencies have been installed (The Windows Azure Tools are installed and present in that directory). The MSBuild flags that I pass in are below:

```
/t:Publish /p:BuildServer=True /p:PublishDir=\\my-hostname\drops\ 
/p:Configuration=Debug;EnableRemoteDebugger=true;VSX64RemoteDebuggerPath="<correct_path>";RemoteDebuggerConnectorCertificateThumbprint="<thumbprint>";RemoteDebuggerConnectorVersion="2.4"
```

I omit the final part of the MSBuild definition required by the instructions: I do not specify a .sln file, because I provide a .cspkg and .cscfg file for publishing. Is specifying a sln file required?

Any other thoughts on where my system is misconfigured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had precisely the same error and after having a closer look at the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets and then the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.RemoteDebugger.targets files, it looks like the registry path specified in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets for the Windows Azure Tools is incorrect if your build server is 64-bit.

To fix it I exported the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio\11.0\2.3 and then edited and imported back to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio\11.0\2.3

Have a look at this line in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets:
$(Registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio\11.0\2.3@InstallPath)

And this line in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.RemoteDebugger.targets:
    $(CloudToolsInstallPath)RemoteDebuggerConnector\

After this all the required files where in the Intermediate path for packaging (ie. obj\Debug)

Comment: This worked: The directory was present in SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft, but not in the base SOFTWARE\Microsoft directory, so after exporting the registry keys, and re-importing them to the correct location, everything worked like a charm.

Comment: I had a follow-up question: I still can't get Remote debugging enabled with these configuration settings. Once the build succeeds, Remote Debugging is still disabled. Did anyone also have a similar problem?

Comment: @c0nn Yes after following up all this I get this error when I try to remote debug the cloud service after being created: "There was a failure to launch the remote debugger."

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having the same issue, you can also specify in the build command the path to the remote debug connector.

For me it was:

```
RemoteDebuggerConnectorPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Azure Tools\Visual Studio 14.0\2.7\RemoteDebuggerConnector\\"
```